# Is every cyclic polygon convex?

Tags: circles, polygons, spheres, polytopes, convex-geometry

More generally, is every n-polytope with all its vertices on an n-sphere convex?
 Among the several images displayed on Wikipedia's [circumscribed circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle) page, none depicts a non-convex polygon.

Comment: In a word, yes.

Comment: That's probably what they said about the Jordan curve theorem too.

Comment: If I had to guess I would say yes. But I don't think I can prove it so I don't know how much it's worth.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown So, have you changed your mind?

Comment: @AmitaiYuval it is the same answerer.

Comment: @mathreadler In the comment, he/she claimed that it is true. The answer shows that it is false.

Comment: @wythagoras: Yes, and it is the same poster, so the answer should be obvious?

Comment: @mathreadler I would expect Lord shark to remove his/her comment if they now believe its content is false.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval: Why remove it? That would destroy any interesting exchange of ideas.

Comment: This is probably true  too: let $B$ be the boundary of a convex set on the $2$-dimensional Euclidean plane.  If $P$ is a polygon with vertices in $B$ such that the edges (sides) of $P$ form a Jordan curve, then $P$ is a convex polygon.  (I believe $P$ can even have infinitely many vertices---or $P$ is an apeirogon.)

Comment: @Batominovski yes it would be natural to generalize the circumscribing figure in the plane.  Cyclic polygons are what led me to the question, so that's what I went with.

Comment: Inducting on the number of sides is surely the easiest approach for polygons, but the result isn't immediate as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a non-convex example in three dimensions. Consider the union of
two tetrahedra, each with base with vertices $(1,0,0)$, $(4/5,3/5,0)$
and $(4/5,-3/5,0)$. One of the tetrahedra has fourth vertex $(0,0,1)$
the other $(0,0,-1)$.

There's no example in the plane.

Comment: You might want to elaborate a bit on the example: All points are on the sphere with midpoint $(0,0,0)$ and radius $1$, and the polytope is not convex because $(0,0,0)$ is on the line between $(0,0,-1)$ and $(0,0,1)$, but not inside the polytope.

Comment: Since I guess the official question is what gets asked in the question and not the title, this answer qualifies for the check mark.

Comment: Surely a pentagram (or any regular star polygon) is an example in the plane?

Comment: @Kundor funny, when I look at a pentagram I always see ten vertices; five pointy ones on the outside and five ones with reflex angles in the middle.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: By most definitions I'm familiar with, the pentagram is combinatorially isomorphic to the pentagon; it has five vertices and five edges. (See e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagram), or Coxeter on star polygons, or, well, I can't actually think of anyone who defines it as you suggest.)